# Crystal Enterprise 9: How to Calculate average for datediff

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, datediff

So I have this statement that calculates the time difference. It uses the previous `mod_date` minus the current `mod_date`. Now I would like to get the average of each users time interval, basically average of `DateDiff`.

Below is the SQL to get the time interval:

```
(DateDiff ("s",previous({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}) ,{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}))/60
```

I've tried something like:

```
 Select AVG(DateDiff ("s",previous({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}) ,{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}))/60
```

But I keep getting prompted for some numerical value on `AVG()`.

Comment: `DateDiff` is not a function that exists by default in Oracle.  Did you create a user-defined function by that name to replicate the function that exists in other databases like SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using it in Crystal 9 as a Report

Comment: Where are you using that query in crystal report?

Comment: In the Formula Fields

Comment: I get, "The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula" error.

Comment: If I type out Average instead of AVG for this statement,  Select    Average(DateDiff ("s",previous({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}) ,{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}))/60 I get, "A field is required here" message